# Ice connection state , Completed vs Connected

Tags: webrtc

Can someone please clarify the difference between **iceConnectionstate:completed** vs **iceConnectionstate:connected**.

When I connect to browsers with webrtc I am able to exchange data using datachannel but for some reason the the iceConnectionstate on browser that made the offer reaming completed wheres the browser that accepted the offers changes to connected.

Any idea if this is normal?

Answer (score 6):

ICE Connection state transition is a bit tricky, with below flow diagram you can get clear idea on possible transitions.

[image: ICE Transport State Diagram]

**In simple words:**
new/checking: *Not at connected*
connected/completed: *Media path is available*
disconnected/failed: *Media path is not available* (Whatever data you are sending on data channel won't reach other end)

Read full summary [here](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtciceconnectionstate-enum)

Still WebRTC team is working hard to make it stable & spec compliant.
Current chrome behavior is confusing so i filed a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=7918), you can star it to get notified.

Comment: There is possibility of transitioning from COMPLETED to CONNECTED. Source: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webrtc/2012Sep/att-0097/WebRTCstatesandcallbacks.pdf   . This is also mentioned in the other answer by Taylor.

Answer (score 6):

In short:

- **connected**: Found a working candidate pair, but still performing connectivity checks to find a better one.
- **completed**: Found a working candidate pair and done performing connectivity checks.

For most purposes, you can probably treat the connected/completed states as the same thing.

Note that, as mentioned by Ajay, there are some notable difference between how the standard defines the states and how they're implemented in Chrome. The main ones that come to mind:

- There's no "end-of-candidates" signaling, so none of those parts of the candidate state definitions are implemented. This means if a remote candidate arrives late, it's possible to go from  "completed" back to "connected" without an ICE restart. Though I assume this is rare in practice.
- The ICE state is actually a combination ICE+DTLS state (see: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=6145). This is because it was implemented before there was such thing as "RTCPeerConnectionState". This can lead to confusion if there's actually a DTLS-level issue, since the only way to really notice is to look in a native Chrome log.

We definitely plan on fixing all the discrepancies. But for a while we held off on it because the standard was still in flux. And right now our priority is more on implementing unified plan SDP and the RtpSender/RtpReceiver APIs.

Comment: Common sense dictatates if 2 peers are connectes they will have the same status but it seems that peer initiating the connection ends up with complete and the peer answering stays in connected.